# slowness in typing and deleting characters using backspace in wpf textbox control

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

In wpf, when I drag/drop a textbox on an empty window and run the application the typing and deleting of characters using backspace is very fast but when I have a large number of controls (around 200+ controls) on a window the typing and deleting of characters using backspace is slow. Especially deleting using backspace. Also rendering of the window becomes slow. Can anybody tell me what is wrong here?

Note: 
1. My operating system is Windows XP (just in case there is a dependency)
2. I have not handled any event of any control. Neither have I added any attribute/event to the window. It is just the default properties of the windows. Please do let me know if I am suppose to add any to make this work

Comment: 200 controls sounds **very** high. Could you explain what you are doing in more detail.

Comment: Do you have bindings to the Text property of the TextBox? And yes, 200 controls sounds way too much.

Comment: 200 controls way too much. You have to reduce the amount of controls by replacing them with a data grid or virtualized list if applicable or you should split them into different view groups and lazy load them. Definitely, 200 controls is wrong.

Comment: The requirement is such that the window contains so many controls. It is a data entry screen and a big one. Also currently there are no bindings being used although bindings will come in the very near future. Currently it is just the design and nothing else.

Comment: @Prince any idea how can i implement lazy load in wpf? Can you direct me to any sites which gives me examples of this functionality?